# Curve translation in Python does not reach expected value

Tags: python, math, sympy

Suppose I have two curves, f(x) and g(x), and I want to evaluate if g(x) is a translation of f(x).
I used Sympy Curve to do the job with the function `translate`. However, I need help to reach the correct result. Consider the two functions:

f(x) = -x^2 and g(x) = -(x+5)^2 + 8

Notice that g is vertically translated by 8 and horizontally translated by 5. Why `at` is not equal to `b` in the following Python code?

```
from sympy import expand, Symbol, Curve, oo

x = Symbol('x')
f = -x**2
g = -(x+5)**2+8

a = Curve((x, f), (x, -oo, oo))
at = a.translate(5,8)
b = Curve((x, g), (x, -oo, oo))

a, at, b, at == b
```

```
>>> (Curve((x, -x**2), (x, -10, 10)),
 Curve((x + 5, 8 - x**2), (x, -10, 10)),
 Curve((x, 8 - (x + 5)**2), (x, -10, 10)),
 False)
```

How could I make this analysis work using this or any other method?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with `sympy.Curve`, but this might be related to this "gotcha" from the sympy documentation: [sympy gotchas: double equal signs](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/explanation/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs)

Comment: Also, I think it should be `at = a.translate(-5,8)`, not `at = a.translate(5,8)`

Comment: Note that it's not completely obvious to test whether the two expressions are equal. You should let `y = x+5`, rewrite `8-x**2` as a function of `y` instead of `x`, then test whether the resulting expression is equivalent to `8 - (y + 5)**2` using `sympy.simplify`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @smichr for the reference about solve_undetermined_coeffs. Here you can find a full answer to my initial problem in Python 3.8.10 and Sympy 1.11.1.

```
from sympy import symbols, Eq, solve_undetermined_coeffs

x, dx, dy = symbols('x dx dy')
f = -x**2
g = -(x+5)**2+8

eq = Eq(f.subs(x,x-dx)+dy,g)
solve_undetermined_coeffs(eq,[dx,dy],x)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Curve` is probably not the right way to do this. If you have univariate functions for which you want to know a x and y translation will make them equal, you could use something like the following:

```py
>>> dx,dy = Symbols('dx dy')
>>> eq = Eq(f.subs(x,x-dx)+dy)
>>> solve_undetermined_coeffs(eq,g),(dx,dy),x)
[(-5, 8)]
```

If there are no values of `dx` and `dy` that will solve the equality, then an empty list will be returned.

Comment: Thanks. I could not run your code as it is in Python 3.8.10, but this is in the right direction with solve_undetermined_coeffs. I will present my code in answer to my question.